# Find issues in jira created between 6am to 3pm for all days of current month using JQL

Tags: jira, jql

I want to filter the issues created between 6am to 3pm, for which I have tried:

```
AND created > startOfDay("+6h")  AND created < startOfDay("+15h")
```

But this only shows the current day issues created between 6am to 3pm.

Can anyone help me to "find the issues created between 6am to 3pm for all days of current month?"

Answer (score 0):

I don´t think that is possible using out of the box JQL unless you find a JQL addon OR use a custom SQL (only SERVER, since that is restricted in CLOUD).